# Are there any particular food macros instructions given in our vedas

Tags: scripture, vedas, food, ayurveda, manuscripts

I would like to follow a strictly sattvik diet. I would like to know if there are any instructions given in the vedas or scriptures about the proportions of protein carbohydrates and fats to be consumed.

Comment: The topics like proportions of protein carbohydrates and fats makes this question fall in the category of scientific speculation , which is off topic here.I am voting to close the post as off topic.

Comment: I think what he is looking for is a dietary plan from vedas or scriptures just like a nutritionist prepares for us. Although I have read lot about sattvik rajsik and tamsik food, i have not come across a dietary plan. Interesting question.

Comment: Swiftpuahkar..no offense but I don't think my question is offtopic. I was just asking if there is any mention of the concept of proteins, carbs and fats in our manuscripts. I am curious to know if they have prescribed any particular proportions in which one must consume the macros. Be a little open minded please. There is a lot to learn and percieve.

Comment: There is definitely dietary restrictions. But it doesn't talk about protein/carbs. For Satvik diet, it must be strictly vegetarian (no meat, eggs, fish), no alcohol. and in addition - no onion, garlic, mushroom (basically Brahmin or Jain diet).